# Execute HTTP request on remote machine

Tags: php, http, curl

I have 2 servers, let's call them `server A` and `server B`. `Server A` is publicly hosted and has a public facing front-end. Users can visit a page on `Server A` and submit a form, which needs to be submitted to a page hosted on a private network that `Server A` does not have access to `Server B`, however does have access to said private network.

What I need to achieve, is for `Server A` formulate the request and then execute it from `Server B`, so that it can hit the page on the private network. The flow would be:

```
1. User submits form
2. Server A formulates an HTTP request and passes it to Server B
3. Server B executes the HTTP request and passes the result back to Server A
3. Server A acts upon the result of the executed request
```

The solution I have so far come up with is to have `Server B` host a PHP built API-like interface with 1 function: `ExecuteHTTPRequest(targetURL, requestBody, parameters)`. `Server A` will then call this function, passing in the URL it wants to hit, the body of the request, and any additional parameters that have been set, and receive the result of the request, as if it had executed it itself.

The downside of this solution is that it means opening up access on an entire port on `Server B` for this specific purpose (albeit only from `Server A`), and that a web server is required to be running on `Server B`. So, I'm wondering if there is some other solution that might be more appropriate?

Comment: I think that an API over HTTP is the best and most flexible solution. But you may set up a database on the serverA and store all your requests in it. ServerB can have a script that connects to database on the serverA and query data from database. So you don't need to open port for input, only output requests.

Comment: @marv255 so essentially a DB driven request queue that is added to by Server A and executed by Server B? An interesting concept... my concern though is that it would have higher latency and higher load (and still require an open port, albeit in the opposite direction as the HTTP one).

Comment: Yes. We have a protected network and a web site (serverA in your case). We have a script on the server in protected network (serverB in your case) that can connect to the web site. On the web site's server database port are open only for serverB's IP. Script is running by cron every minute and getting only new data, maximal latency is one minute.

Comment: @marv255 in this particular use case the latency needs to be minimal (the user will be waiting for a response, so a 1 minute delay wouldn't be a great user experience). I appreciate the suggestion though